# How to drop "Chapter X" in a particular chapter?

Tags: sectioning, chapters

Is there a way to just drop the Chapter X name in a particular chapter? I tried these two but they change things across all chapters:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
```

Comment: Use `\chapter*`.

Comment: Shall it appear in the table of contents anyway? Do you want to use labels and references with it?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes I want it to appear in toc, and reference it from the other chapters. The \label seems not working.

Comment: @user3639557: I assume, that you have used `\chapter*` then -- this does not use `\refstepcounter` (so the label is wrong, most likely) and the chapter does not appear in the ToC. You just want to get rid of the chapter title header having the chapter number then?

Comment: If you remove the chapter number, what should the label refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed the `book` class for this.

The (unstarred) chapter head is setup and typeset with `\@makechapterhead` with the lines

```
\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
```

This can be wrapped in an `\ifusechapterhead` conditional that defaults to true and does nothing if it is set to false with `\usechapterheadfalse` on demand.

Please note, that after using `\usechapterheadfalse` this state persists until `\usechapterheadtrue` is applied.

```
\documentclass{book}


\newif\ifusechapterhead
\usechapterheadtrue

\makeatletter

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
      \ifusechapterhead
      \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
      \par\nobreak
      \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo} \label{foo} % Normal

Here we are in chapter \ref{foo} and chapter \ref{foobar} is not numbered, appears in ToC, but the references work anyway.


\blindtext

\usechapterheadfalse
\chapter{Foobar} \label{foobar}
\blindtext
\usechapterheadtrue
\blindtext

\end{document}
```